# How do I remove specific characters generated by python at the end of an excel cell?

Tags: python, pandas

When I run my script, it generates an excel format in exactly how I want it except for a character at the end of every cell as follows:

[image]

The script is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("file.docx")
doc = word.ActiveDocument

Entity = []
for i in (list(range(3, 9)) + list(range(11,42))):
   table = doc.Tables(i)
   Entity.append(table.Cell(Row =2, Column =2).Range.Text)


combine_Table = {'Entity': Entity,}

labels = [list(range(1,38))]
df = pd.DataFrame(combine_Table , index=labels)                
df.to_excel("return.xlsx")
```

Is there something I can put in my code that will remove this character?

Comment: I would assume that the offending character is an end of line. A simple way would be to dump the content of (some of) the problematic cells from the Python code: `rawtext = str(df[index, col])` `print(rawtext, [hex(ord(i)) for i in rawtext)`

Comment: @SergeBallesta it occurs in every cell so I cannot delete the content. I had an idea to include a list of allowable characters (A-Z, 0-9) in order to remove any unwanted characters, but do not know how I can do this

Comment: I think it would be interesting to make sure of what happens before trying to apply a fix. That was the reason for my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Believe this somewhat solves the problem. It is not perfect, but it help. It will take the information in column B, clean it and then place that information in column AA, removing the extra character.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/.../.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

for row_num in range(1, 38):
    sheet['AA{}'.format(row_num)] = '=CLEAN(B{})'.format(row_num)

wb.save('C:/Users/.../.xlsx')
```